# Can I treat "of course" and "of course not" like "yes" and "no"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, expressions

Which of these two expressions is correct?

> 1) Of course not, I am here.
>
> 2) Of course not, I am not here.

For example:

> Yes, he is a boy

The word "yes" emphatically introduces a positive statement. It could not be followed by a negative statement as "yes, he is not a boy." Likewise, "no, he is not a boy." The word "no" has to be followed by a negative statement.

Can I treat "of course" and "of course not" like "yes" and "no"?

Comment: Maybe you could give some background on what situation you’re talking about. I’m having trouble thinking of a case in which one would say, “I am not here.” I guess it could be if she was pointing to a location on a map, in which case either form could work (although the double negative certainly makes the second one sound awkward).

Comment: I am not here is a fabricated example, but grammatically correct. My own guess is "of course" is equivalent to "yes" and "of course not" to "no". If my guess is right, then it should be,of course I am here; of course not, I am not here.

Comment: If "I am not here" is generating confusion, perhaps it would be worthwhile to alter your example expressions. I'm not sure myself what some other possibilities might be.

Comment: "Yes" can be followed by a negative statement. "No" can be followed by a positive statement. You're conflating grammar with meaning in context. "Is your baby a girl?" > "No, he is a boy." That being said, "of course" and "of course not" can generally be treated as "yes" and "no," respectively.

Comment: I am strongly of the opinion that yes cannot be followed by a negative statement and no by positive one. In your example, I answer "no, it is not a girl." The negatives no and not do not make her a girl. Rather, no and not are simply echoing each other and she is still not a girl.

Comment: You are wrong, though, Choy.

Comment: You did not explain why I was wrong.

Comment: Q: Is Sam a girl? A: No, he's a boy (because Sam is short for Samuel) i.e. Q:Is Sam a girl? A: No, of course [*he is*] not.

Comment: Q: Are you in New York? A: Of course [I am] not. I'm still in Milan. A: Of course [I am], I flew over last night.

Comment: I have responded to a similar argument by Scott on 6/14/14 at 1:20 that brought me a badge. Please refer to that response. I am deeply disappointed by people who have been rewarded so many badges while demonstrating in such a childish manner. There must be a serious problem with our educational system, badge awarding criteria, and mentality here in the US.

Answer (score 3):

I (largely) agree with njboot and Matt Эллен –
positive and negative utterances can be intermixed, fairly freely. 
(I used the word “utterances” because “clauses” is too restrictive –
“Yes”, “No”, and “Of course” are not clauses.) 
I would say that the short answer is:
when you’re answering a question, you answer the question. 
And then, if you want, you provide amplifying/clarifying information. 
Here are some examples that I consider valid:

- *Are you in Hungary?*
  Yes, I’m in Hungary.
- *Are you in Hungary?*
  No, I’m not in Hungary.
- *Are you in Hungary?*
  No, I’m in Austria. 
                                          ← (negative followed by positive)
- *Are you in Hungary?*
  Yes, I left Austria two days ago.
- *Are you in Hungary?*
  Yes, I’m in not Austria any more.                ← (positive followed by negative)
- *Are you hungry?*
  Yes, I haven’t eaten in two days.                  ← (positive followed by negative)

I guess, in any of the above,
“Yes” could be replaced by “Of course” and “No” could be replaced by “Of course not”
(but I still believe that double negatives
like “Of course not, I’m not.” sound wrong to my ear). 
Whether such a substitution would make sense would depend on the context
(i.e., what the other person might reasonably expect). 
For example, if I were in a place that I was scheduled to be in on that day,
I might say, “Of course”; if I were delayed or detoured, I definitely would not. 
“Of course” and “Of course not” may be equivalent to “Yes” and “No” ***when they are followed by a comma*** (or possibly a semicolon), but watch out for cases like

- *Are you at the South Pole?*

  - No, I’m not at the South Pole.
  - Of course I’m not at the South Pole.
    (This means, “Of course not, I’m not at the South Pole.”,
    but I don’t believe anybody would ever say that.)
  - No I’m not at the South Pole.                ← (this is wrong; it needs the comma after “No”)

Comment: Let me be clear by the following examples: yes, I am Mr. Y ; no, I am not Mr.Y. Nobody could challenge the correctness of these two sentences grammatically. However, if I say : no, I am Mr. Y, then you would not know what I am denying and you only know what I am affirming; further questions would be required because I may be denying Mr. X, or Mr.Z, or Mr.A, or anything. It is due to this suppression of answer that yes, positive and no, negative. Again, what I am not sure is whether of course and of course not could be substituted for yes and no.

Comment: Well, since you seem to be thoroughly confused (or else I am), let me put it to you this way: ***Nobody would ever*** begin a conversation with “Yes, …”, “No, …”, “Of course, …” or “Of course not, …”. Those would be used ***only*** in response to a yes/no question. If you’re asking the grammatical correctness of these forms at the beginning of a conversation, you’re barking up the wrong tree; like [“Colorless green ideas sleep furiously”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously), they are grammatically correct, but semantically nonsensical.

Comment: The mystery of language could not be significantly explained by Noam Chomsky, but could be credibly, to a certain extent, reflected on the reports by the US astronomer in the late 60's and the Chinese astronomer in the early 2000 when they were on their lunar trips, answering same questions with two entirely different languages. I do not intend to elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that each of them has its own place, because I consider the part after "Of course not" as the reason as why we answered "no" that is implied by the "Of course no".

Those two expressions are, of course, grammatically correct, so perhaps you're asking which one is sensical. My answer is that both of them can be made sensical, depending on the question.

To make the expressions sensical, one just need to find out a question for each expression which, when answered by "No", will have "I am here" or "I am not here" as the explanation.

For the first:

> *John and Mary in a room with a bed and a computer table. John is sitting in front of the computer table, not seeing Mary lying on the bed*
>
> John: (shouting, thinking Mary is outside) Mary, are you near the mailbox now?
>
> Mary: (to John's surprise) Of course not, I am here.

Scott's example is a good one for the second:

> *John and Mary having online conversation with John apparently controlling Mary's computer remotely through screen sharing software*
>
> Mary: Can you see the penguins from your place?
>
> John: Of course not, (pointing to the north pole on the map with his cursor) I am not here.

Comment: Of course, even if he were at the _North_ Pole, John would not be able to see [penguins](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071216212546AArlmVg).  ***Of course he wouldn’t!*** :) (Then again, he probably wouldn’t be able to _at_ the South Pole, either.)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow "Yes" by a negative statement. Consider a court case:

> **Prosecutor**: "So, Mr. Jones, you were not at the bar the night of December 23rd, correct?"
>
> **Mr. Jones**: "Yes, I was not at the bar that night."

You can do the same thing with "of course" and "of course not".

> "Of course I wasn't drunk, you turd-eater!" said Henrietta.

So as there are no rules requiring "Yes/No" to be followed by solely positive/negative statements, there are no rules requiring "Of course/Of course" not to be followed solely by positive/negative statements, respectively.

Comment: It is a fallacy of appeal to authority. The date December 23rd is damningly wrong. There are two ways of writing a date: December 23, or 23rd December. December 23rd is both grammatically and logically wrong. No discussion on other points are warranted.

Comment: @Choy: English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts. Of course you’re free to use this site (note the use of a leading “of course” ***without a following comma***), but you might be better served by [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com), as you don’t seem to fit into EL&U’s target audience.

Comment: @Choy: In particular, “December 23rd” is perfectly correct. There are many acceptable ways of writing the date 12/23 (two days before Christmas), including “December 23”, “23 December”, and “the 23rd of December”. While “23rd December” might not *quite* be “damningly wrong” – most English speakers would understand it, and it might be common in certain contexts (maybe legal documents) – very few English speakers would use it, in my experience.

Comment: Grammar is logic applied to speech; we condemn the sins, but not the sinners. 10 players, a cardinal number; the 10th player, an ordinal number; the player 10, a nominal player; and no others are logically established. We say August the second (8/2), but we write August two (8/2). Our speech is wrong, our writing right.